# How to set leftmost and rightmost bit of ushort in C#

Tags: c#, enums, bit

I need to code enum(eration), which will be convertible to ushort number and back. For some reason i need to work with bits (not bytes).

```
[Flags]
public enum XFlags : ushort//word
{
    None = 0,
    Sequenced = "option enabled if LEFTmost bit is == 1",
    Extra = "option enabled if RIGHTmost bit is == 1"
};
```

My problem is that i don't know how to specify bits. Also i actually need to use [Flags] feature, to use few flags for flag variable. So use of both flags should give me (ushort) bits 1000000000000001?

Is that possible?

Comment: I guess you do not mean hexadecimal `0x1000000000000001`, but dual `1000000000000001`? that would be `0x8001` in hex

Comment: Yes. It was problem why i didn't undesrtood how 0x8000 appeared. Now clear. Thx(sry)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (it basically is exactly what you expressed in your code, turned into `ushort`):

```
[Flags]
public enum XFlags : ushort//word
{
    None = 0,
    Sequenced = 0x8000,
    Extra = 0x0001
}
```

Now combining `XFlags.Sequenced` with `XFlags.Extra` you end up with a `ushort`, having the leftmost and rightmost bit set.

Comment: Wow. That's what i need. But i didn't understand how 8000 become the first bit. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Loryan55 8 is 1000 in binary.

Comment: You're welcome! `0x8000` is just hexadecimal (I guess you might wanna read a little bit about the hexadecimal system) for the dual number `1000000000000000` ;)